primitive idempotent
I’ve tried to prove: $R$ local, Artin ring $\phi:End(P) \rightarrow End(Q) $   ,$e\in End(P) $ is primivite idempotent and $P$ and $Q$ free module so $P= (\oplus R_i)$ and $Q=(\oplus R_j) $then how can i prove
$e(\oplus R_i) \cong \phi e(\oplus R_j)$
this is Ip-isomorphism actually?
I think $R \cong R$ but how ?
